# Recharts - Set domain without axis in BarCharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm currently using Recharts to implement our Bar Chart. Something like this.

```js
const {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer
} = Recharts;


const data = [
  { name: "Page A", uv: 4270 },
  { name: "Page B", uv: 17 },
  { name: "Page C", uv: 2 },
  { name: "Page D", uv: 3 },
  { name: "Page E", uv: 1 },
  { name: "Page F", uv: 2 },
  { name: "Page G", uv: 1 }
];

const SimpleAreaChart = () => {
  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer>
      <BarChart
        layout="vertical"
        data={data}
        margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <YAxis type="category" dataKey="name" />
        <XAxis type="number" domain={[0, 5000]} />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(<SimpleAreaChart />, rootElement);
```

```css
#container {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/recharts/umd/Recharts.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" />
```

**I do not want to show XAxis.**

But without `XAxis`, the maximum bar is just about 70% of the `BarChart`

I can not find any way to make the maximum bar to get about 90% of `BarChart` but setting `domain` in `Axis`.

Is there any way I can still set `domain` and not show `XAxis`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `hide` in `Axis` component.

```
<XAxis type="number" domain={[0, 5000]} hide />
```